# Manipulate the extreme values used to develop fill in a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I use `ggplot2` and a package called `rnaturalearth` to develop a map of European countries, with different colour for each country dependent on each country's score.

The problem: I want to define which value `ggplot2` uses when defining colours for each country. Now, `ggplot2` uses the lowest and highest values to define the extremes of the scale; I want to define the extremes by myself (that is, use lower and higher extreme values and thereby manipulate the colours).

Data:

```
Data <- structure(list(iso_a2 = structure(c("AT", "BE", "CH", "CZ", "DE", 
"DK", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "HU", "IE", "IT", "LU", "NL", 
"NO", "PL", "PT", "SE", "SI"), label = "Country", format.stata = "%2s"), 
    values = c(0.498210763764124, 0.39731454174295, 1.28199768407053, 
    -0.645219093750782, 0.0505441315876436, 1.91304897270232, 
    0.0802428116303039, 1.40711329859048, 0.0627266707521129, 
    0.191581882192026, 0.181001731032278, 0.356882787996765, 
    0.168525492955127, 0.276086485962419, 1.12477750307519, 0.892265586989629, 
    1.22957941831254, -0.942690852748792, -0.412722832958249, 
    1.34589962077675, -0.484403677107108)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

This is the code I'm currently running:

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Use map from rnaturalearth, restrict to European countries
world  <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
Europe <- world[which(world$continent == "Europe"), ]

# Add Data to the map
Data <- merge(Europe, Data, by = "iso_a2", all = TRUE)

# Draw map with colours
ggplot(Data) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = -values), size = 0.25) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(-10.8, 32), ylim = c(35, 71.3), expand=FALSE) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme(
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "grey90")
```

The result is:

[image: Resulting map]

I would like to manipulate these colours not by defining the colours per se, but by manipulating the scale `ggplot2` uses (now presumable going from the lowest to the highest value in `data$values`).

Manipulating the colours directly by using `scale_fill_gradient` would not be a good idea since **I am developing several maps** and the whole idea is that **a specific value should result in the same colour independently of what values are represented** in the specific map.

---

**EDIT**. I have decided to use a simple solution, adding two rows to the data frame with constant extreme values across all maps.

Something like:

```
df_high <- data.frame("SJ",  1.63, 2.2)
df_low  <- data.frame("AZ", -1.5, -2.02)

names(df_high) <- c("cntry", "values_1", "values_2")
names(df_low)  <- c("cntry", "values_1", "values_2")

new_map_2010 <- rbind(old_map_2010, df_high, df_low)
new_map_2012 <- rbind(old_map_2012, df_high, df_low)
```

This is not a programmer's solution, but it is easier for me than what appears to be the alternative solution. Consequently, I am not able to decide whether the solution below by @Pedro Alencar works or not.

**So PLEASE, if anyone tries Pedro Alencar's suggestion and finds it works, please tell me** and I will accept his solution. For now, I can only upvote it.

(My own solution can easily be adapted by using code to identify the highest and lowest values across all data frames, then add new rows with these values - and add these specific rows to all data frames. All done with code, but still not really a programmer's solution...)

Comment: Have you considered ´ggplot2::scale_fill_manual()´? It allows for named value = color pairs, which should fit your use case / if I read it correctly...

Comment: Doesn't scale_fill_manual manipulate the colours directly rather than the values ggplot uses to define which colour to use?

Comment: A solution I have thought of, is to add two countries outside the map to the data frame and to give these countries the same value across all maps to be developed - one the highest value and one the lowest value. That would make sure the scale is the same across all maps... 

But it doesn't seem to be a very elegant solution...

Answer (score 1):

Create a data frame with values (rounded) and colours:

```
df_colors <- data.frame(values_round = seq(round(min(Data$values, na.rm = T),2), 
                                    round(max(Data$values, na.rm = T),2),
                                    by = 0.01))
df_colors$color <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))(nrow(df_colors))
df_colors$values_round <- as.integer(df_colors$values_round*100)
```

See that I turned the values to integer. This is because I was facing some rounding errors.

Then create a new column `values_round` in your original data frame (`Data`) and `left_join` with `df_colors`:

```
Data$values_round <- as.integer(round(Data$values, 2)*100)
Data <- left_join(Data, df_colors, by = 'values_round')
```

Now you can plot:

```
ggplot(Data) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = color), size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-10.8, 32), ylim = c(35, 71.3), expand=FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_identity(aesthetics = "fill")
```

Note that you'll need to identify the maximum and minimum for your entire dataset in order to get a fixed `df_colors`.

Comment: Thanks. The package itself seems great, but I'm not yet able to understand how I can apply it to my case. I will read on RColorBrewer and see if I understand.

Comment: Sure. You should have a column with the respective column for each value. you then shold use this colour column as input (`aes(fill = colours_column)`). Aslo add `scale_colour_identity()` instead of the `scale_fill _gradient`

Comment: Sorry for not being able to figure out whether your solution works.

Comment: no worries @cibr, I managed to install the package (very interesting. I'm probably going to use it). And posted the complete solution. Congrats on the great question.

Comment: Great. Unfortunately, I cannot test this now as I am occupied with other tasks (currently, I rely on the ad hoc solution I developed). Glad my question inspired your work!