# Using a sequential color Palette across multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently using the following code to generate a sequential gradient from red to blue.

```
color_range = colorRampPalette(c('red', 'blue'))
graph1 = color_range(length_of_data1) 
graph2 = color_range(length_of_data2)
graph3 = color_range(lenght_of_data3)
```

However I have 3 data sets which I wish to apply this color palette to and I would like the scale to be the same between graphs so that the data are comparable. (IE what is similar value in one graph appears the same color in the next).

Comment: Please provide a sample data. Also you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67969541/manipulate-the-extreme-values-used-to-develop-fill-in-a-map/67969918#67969918

Comment: you can either round up the values from your data and assign the colour for each group or add to each dataframe two dummy lines with max and min values that are the same in all of them.

Comment: Pedro this worked great, is there a way to suppress the graphing of the min/max values?

Comment: Not sure what kind of plot you want to do, but I suppose you give it a position that is out of the plotting area, then you could crop both axes